# How to convert slug to Latin?

Tags: craft3

Tell me please. I am adding an entry with a Russian title to the section. Slug is also obtained in Russian. How can this be fixed? I want to add an entry with the title "Привет мир", slug converted to "privet-mir"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`limitAutoSlugsToAscii`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#limitautoslugstoascii) config setting to `true`.